# react native multistep wizard formik yup

Tags: react-native, formik

Hi I am new to react native.
I have react native project in which I have implement multistep form wizard with formik yup validation. Currently I have implemented multistep form wizard with formik yup validation in react.

How can I implement or convert it to react native.

Below is the code which implement in react.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { ErrorMessage, Field, Form, Formik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

const Wizard = ({ children, initialValues, onSubmit }) => {
  const [stepNumber, setStepNumber] = useState(0);
  const steps = React.Children.toArray(children);
  const [snapshot, setSnapshot] = useState(initialValues);

  const step = steps[stepNumber];
  const totalSteps = steps.length;
  const isLastStep = stepNumber === totalSteps - 1;

  const next = values => {
    setSnapshot(values);
    setStepNumber(Math.min(stepNumber + 1, totalSteps - 1));
  };

  const previous = values => {
    setSnapshot(values);
    setStepNumber(Math.max(stepNumber - 1, 0));
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (values, formikBag) => {    
    if (isLastStep) {
      return onSubmit(values, formikBag);
    } else {
      next(values);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={snapshot}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      validationSchema={step.props.validationSchema}
    >
      {formik => (
        <Form>
          <p>
            Step {stepNumber + 1} of {totalSteps}
          </p>
          {step}
          <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
            {stepNumber > 0 && (
              <button onClick={() => previous(formik.values)} type="button">
                Back
              </button>
            )}
            <div>
              <button disabled={formik.isSubmitting} type="submit">
                {isLastStep ? "Submit" : "Next"}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

const WizardStep = ({ children }) => children;

const Demo = () => {
    const submitform=(values)=>{
      alert('First name:'+values.firstName+' Last name:'+values.lastName+' Mobile:'+values.mobile+' Email:'+values.email);
    }

return(
<>
  <Wizard
    initialValues={{
      email: "",
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      mobile:''
    }}
    onSubmit={values => submitform(values)}
    
  >
    <WizardStep
      validationSchema={Yup.object({
        firstName: Yup.string().required("required"),
        lastName: Yup.string().required("required")
      })}
    >
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
        <Field
          autoComplete="given-name"
          component="input"
          id="firstName"
          name="firstName"
          placeholder="First Name"
          type="text"
        />
        <ErrorMessage className="error" component="div" name="firstName" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <Field
          autoComplete="family-name"
          component="input"
          id="lastName"
          name="lastName"
          placeholder="Last Name"
          type="text"
        />
        <ErrorMessage className="error" component="div" name="lastName" />
      </div>
    </WizardStep>
    <WizardStep
      validationSchema={Yup.object({
        mobile: Yup.number('Invalid mobile').min(10,"Invalid mobile").required("required")
      })}
    >
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="mobile">Mobile</label>
        <Field
          autoComplete="mobile"
          component="input"
          id="mobile"
          name="mobile"
          placeholder="Mobile"
          type="text"
        />
        <ErrorMessage className="error" component="div" name="mobile" />
      </div>
    </WizardStep>
    <WizardStep
      validationSchema={Yup.object({
        email: Yup.string()
          .email("Invalid email address")
          .required("required")
      })}
    >
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
        <Field
          autoComplete="email"
          component="input"
          id="email"
          name="email"
          placeholder="Email"
          type="text"
        />
        <ErrorMessage className="error" component="div" name="email" />
      </div>
    </WizardStep>
  </Wizard>
</>
  )
}

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Demo />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```